# C++ Compiler (cl) does not see parent virtual method with same child method name

Tags: c++, oop, overriding, virtual-functions

I have a C++ code, using inheritance and function overriding at the same time, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
    protected:
        virtual void G() const = 0;
    public:
        virtual void G(const string& s) const final { G(); }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    protected:
        virtual void G() const override { cout<<"Child G"; }
};

int main()
{
    Child *c = new Child();
    c->G("test");
    return 0;
}
```

When compile, I got error: `Child::G: function does not take 1 arguments`. But when I use Parent pointer like this:

```
Parent *c = new Child();
```

It works. Alternatively if I change public `G` method's name, it works too.

What is wrong about using same name (`G`) for both methods?

Comment: A thorough explanation of why this happens is available [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#overload-derived)

Comment: It is a good response to *WHY* aspect of my question. If it was an answer it would be best answer, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce the parent member into the child with a `using` declaration:

```
class Child : public Parent
{
    protected:
        virtual void G() const override { cout<<"Child G"; }
    public:
        using Parent::G;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this is indeed to introduce the `Parent`'s method into the scope of the `Child` class with a `using` declaration, as @Jans kindly points out. As to *why* this is the case is simply a matter of how the compiler searches through scopes when searching for a method to match your function call. A break down of what's happening is as follows:

- in `Child *c = new Child(); c->G("test");`, the compiler sees a call to some method `G` on an object of type `Child`. It then searches the scope of `Child` to look for a match.
- The compiler, when exploring the scope of `Child`, sees only `Child::G() const`. It does *not* see `Parent::G(const std::string&) const`, which even though you want it to be included via inheritance, is in a *different scope*. In a sense, `Child::G` is *shadowing* `Parent::G`. Without a candidate match, the compiler would have kept searching into the `Parent` scope.
- The compiler thus is happy having found `Child::G`. However, this is a function accepting no arguments, and you tried to call it with `"test"`. The function call then fails because of a mismatch in the parameters.

As stated, you need to bring `Parent::G` into the same scope as `Child::G` for overloading to happen as intended, with `using Parent::G` inside the body of `Child`.

Source: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#overload-derived